# Change SSIS package authors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

We have a job, that contains SSIS packages. It is SQL Server 2005. A dba named xyz created those SSIS packages. It was running fine in the when the job kicks in. However, he left, and the company wanted to change all his ownership from all objects, such as databases, jobs, and maintenance plans ownership to sa.

As we did this, lots of errors came up. Every other job runs fine, only those jobs with SSIS package are failing.

Error is :

> Executed as user: Mycompany\sqlagentserviceAccount. Unable to open Step output file.  The step failed.

However, the SSIS package was created by the xyz DBA. For troubleshooting we did change the job ownership to xyz dba name, but it still failed.

Any help on how to change the SSIS packages back to his name, or any other tips, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check the security setting of the package configuration (inside the package). The default for a package is "EncryptSenstiveWithUserKey", which means only that user can modify the package or read the connection manager objects.

You also don't provide how the packages are deployed. If they are deployed to the Package Store or SQL Server then the security setting mentioned above does not apply. If they are using file level deployment who executes the job or owns it can play a role in the issue you are having....meaning you will have to adjust the packages.

[image]